# Automatically open Web Inspector for popup windows?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, webkit

I'm working on an app where I need to open a new browser window, and I need to debug some JS.

The web inspector opens fine in the main window, but when the popup (new browser window) opens, the web inspector is not opened automatically for that window, so I'm not able to hit any breakpoints there.

Is there a way to have all windows have a web inspector open by default?

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach by referencing the Firebug js file in the pages or a footer which is used in the  page  - Inturn it will trigger the web inspector